# Preselecting Dropdown value in .Net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, automation

I have a webform whose fields change based on the value of a dropdown.  Is there a way I could have a link to this page select one of these values when it loads.

For example, if the form was about traveling, the external "car" link would autoselect "car" in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a QueryString parameter, such as `?preselect=car` and then act on the value of that parameter in your code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<script runat="server">

    private void page_load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("preselect"))
        {
            MyDropDownList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                .Where(li => li.Value == Request.QueryString["preselect"].ToString())
                .First().Selected = true;
        }
    }

</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="MyDropDownList">
            <asp:ListItem Value="asdf">Something</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="car">Car</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```